# Crash when rendering?

Tags: rendering

**Machine and Software Specifics:**

- Desktop with i7 CPU AMD Radeon HD 6670 video card (DVI)
- 8 gigs RAM
- 500 gig hard drive
- Windows 10

This machine only crashes when I render, which I do from a command prompt. Sometimes it works just fine, usually it does not.

Are there any settings that I should check to stop this from happening?

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean Blender crash or OS crash ? What kind of scene are you rendering ? Please add some details (text and maybe screenshots of scene / errors) and if possible a [blend file](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)

Comment: It would be useful if you described the scene you are trying to render. Most crashes are because the complexity of the scene exceeds the resources available. Maybe you have way too many vertices, subdivisions, large textures, complex simulations, particles etc. It could also be some add-on acting up or some incompatibility with your GPU.  Chances are you need to simplify your scene by reducing the size, decimating, simplifying, baking, etc... or render in a more powerful computer... Hard to tell with the available information.

Comment: This is a OS crash, and is probably hardware related, but only happens when I render an animation - I use the command line, and create images. I tried lowering thread count from 8 to 4 - but no luck. just looking for other ideas

Comment: Scene size doesn't matter. I had a hot air balloon with flames that flew, and moving people on board that rendered fine. But I had a simple bouncing ball that caused a crash.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question has nothing to do with Blender, but is instead about a crash that isn't caused by Blender.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bad BIOS setting. SATA drive RAID Mode was "IDE" not "RAID".
 Reinstalled "Winders 10". Everything much more stable.